# odd even selector for div issue

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div that I populate with a list/rows of divs 
now I need to give alternate color to rows.
for that I am doing the following

```
$('#PlatformErrorsTableData').html(table1Html);
$('#PlatformErrorsTableData div:nth-child(even)').css("background-color", "aqua");
```

the table1Html looks like the following:

```
<div>
  <span class="platformTable columnWidth10">Originator1</span>
  <span class="platformTable truncate">Message for Originator# 1</span>
  <span class="platformTable columnWidth15">Server1</span>
  <span class="platformTable columnWidth20">5:50 PM</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="platformTable columnWidth10">Originator2</span>
  <span class="platformTable truncate">Message for Originator# 2</span>
  <span class="platformTable columnWidth15">Server2</span>
  <span class="platformTable columnWidth20">5:50 PM</span>
</div> 
<div>
  <span class="platformTable columnWidth10">Originator3</span>
  <span class="platformTable truncate">Message for Originator# 3</span>
  <span class="platformTable columnWidth15">Server3</span>
  <span class="platformTable columnWidth20">5:50 PM</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="platformTable columnWidth10">Originator4</span>
  <span class="platformTable truncate">Message for Originator# 4</span>
  <span class="platformTable columnWidth15">Server4</span>
  <span class="platformTable columnWidth20">5:50 PM</span>
</div>
```

Now the issue is that the color aqua is not being shown in the screen, however if I inspect the div in firebug, it has background-color set to aqua.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try setting an explicit height on the `div` to start.  If that works you most likely have an issue with CSS and you may need something like `overflow: hidden;` on them (after removing the height).  Also make sure the `span`s have a transparent background.

Comment: could you give us a demo fiddle?

Comment: Try setting some other CSS property like margin or border, it might be more explicit that background color. Like Matt said the inner spans might have non transparent background and might be hiding it. Instead of spans try putting just some dummy text in the divs to verify.

Comment: Try setting it to `#0FF` instead

Comment: @MattWhipple: i gave overflow:hidden and it worked like charm.
can you please put is as answer so that I can mark it as answer and it may help anyone else also.

Comment: Please refer the attached screen,It is working, isn't it? [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vPhJc/4/) ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5xbUq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code works fine here

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TwVMn/)

i think there is some problem with your css styling try setting

`overflow:hidden`

and also provide `min-height` to your div

may be that can help you

Answer (score 2):

You use css code instead of jquery

```
#PlatformErrorsTableData div:nth-child(2n){
   background:#a5a5a5;
}

#PlatformErrorsTableData div:nth-child(2n+1){
   background:#eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an explicit height on the `div`s to start. If that works you most likely have an issue with CSS and you may need something like `overflow: hidden;` on them (after removing the height). Also make sure the `span`s have a transparent background.